# Get XML scheme from XML file using PL/SQL

Tags: xml, oracle

I have pl/sql procedure, that parse xml file and import it to different tables. But this xml from external system, so it is hard to understand, when they change the scheme. I need get XML scheme from new file and compare it to the previously imported using PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to register external xml-schema in your database using `dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema` and then to use `XmlType.isSchemaValid` to check external xml by this schema -

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema('test',
  3  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  4  <xs:schema xmlns="test"
  5             xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  6             elementFormDefault="qualified"
  7             attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  8      <xs:element name="root">
  9          <xs:complexType>
 10              <xs:sequence>
 11                  <xs:element name="name"/>
 12                  <xs:element name="lastName"/>
 13              </xs:sequence>
 14          </xs:complexType>
 15      </xs:element>
 16  </xs:schema>');
 17  end;
 18  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> declare
  2    xml XmlType := XmlType('<root><name>John</name><lastName>Johanson</lastName></root>');
  3    xml2 XmlType := XmlType('<root><name>John</name></root>');
  4  begin
  5    if xml.isSchemaValid('test') = 1 then
  6      dbms_output.put_line('xml valid');
  7    else
  8      dbms_output.put_line('xml not valid');
  9    end if;
 10    if xml2.isSchemaValid('test') = 1 then
 11      dbms_output.put_line('xml2 valid');
 12    else
 13      dbms_output.put_line('xml2 not valid');
 14    end if;
 15  end;
 16  /
xml valid
xml2 not valid

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: The main problem is that they dont share scheme, file only, so i need to get this scheme from the file. But it is usefull information anyway =)

Comment: You can generate XSD once manually (or by using online resources like http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html), then register it into database and check files using method isSchemaValid.

Comment: Seems i have no option to generate this using PL/SQL...tnx for your advice.